# How do you display a version number on a footer file?

Tags: deployment

When I deploy my Drupal code, I build an artifact with BLT. I would like to write a file of some kind with the version number (tag provided to the artifact) that could then be read and displayed in the footer.

Where is the best place to write this file in a Drupal directory?

What is the best method to read from the file and display on the page safely?

Is there a different/better method altogether that I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I do it is to commit a text file and then check that live. This can be done while building the project in CI. Here is an example (note your CI variables may vary):

In one of the final steps before the artifact deploys to the server, you can do:

```
deploy:
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_TAG > path/to/drupal/docroot/themes/custom/yourtheme/version.txt
    - git add/commit steps...
    - git push ...
```

Then visiting that URL in the browser will tell you what 'version' that is, made from your CI variable.

Comment: That gets me 90% of the way. A few tweaks for my particulars and it should be good. Thanks.

Comment: I have added a preprocess function for my page template to read the contents of this page and display in the footer. `$variables['version'] = file_get_contents(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/../version.txt');` And then my Jenkins function is writing to the file from the passed in parameter of the version and committing. No need to push in my case as it will be in the artifact and not need to be in the master branch itself.